# How to import GRPC Data to Grafana?

Tags: grpc, grafana

In our application, we have a grpc endpoint to check the health of the application.

When we run the following command from our local machine,

`grpcurl --plaintext localhost:5080 MyApp.Connector.HealthService/GetStatus`

we will get the result in following JSON format.

```
{
   "Status": "Alive",
   "latestRecordTimestamp": 1682483715
}
```

I tried to find plugins that can do this but the only thing that is closest to what I am trying to do is Infinity datasource plugin by Sriram but it does not seem like it supports grpcurl.

Comment: Interesting question. I was going to propose that you look at the Prometheus (!) [Blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/) as this includes a [gRPC probe](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md#grpc_probe) **but** you're not using Prometheus and you're not using the [gRPC Health Checking Protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) (which you may want to consider).

Comment: [`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) is an excellent tool but you probably don't want to use it as the basic for an integration with Grafana because (a) that integration doesn't currently exist; (b) it would provide a shim over gRPC which you want; (c) it uses JSON to represent Protobufs for convenience. Grafana has a Go [SDK](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/backend/grafana-plugin-sdk-for-go/) and it should (!) be relatively straightforward to wrap this around your Healthcheck service stubs.

Comment: Your health check service's response includes a timestamp (`lastRecordTimestamp`). Usually (!?) it is the responsibility of the client/caller to record the timestamp and doing so would simplify your gRPC message. You'll note that the [gRPC Health Checking Protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) reports only the `status`.

Comment: Lastly, it may be worth submitting a feature request against the [Grafana Infinity Datasource](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/) to see whether they are considering supporting gRPC.